# Replace content in one column with another column R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, grepl

I am working with some survey data and I would like to replace the contents of one survey item/column with another survey item, while keeping original cell contents. Ex - replace Q2_1.x with Q2_1.y if Q2_1.x is missing (missing coded as "-99" or coded as character_NA).

**Here is an example of my data:**

```
ibrary(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
ibrary(readr)

org_dat <- read_table('ID   Q2_1.x  Q2_2.x  Q2_1.y  Q2_2.y  Q14_1.x Q14_1.y Q15
    1   Yes NA  NA  NA  Sometimes   NA  NA
    2   -99 NA  No  NA  NA  Always  Yes
    3   Yes NA  Yes NA  NA  NA  NA
    4   -99 NA  NA  No  NA  Yes No 
    5   NA  -99 NA  NA  NA  Always  NA
    6   -99 NA  NA  No  NA  NA  NA') %>% mutate_all(as.character)
```

**Here is my desired output:**

```
dat_out <- read_table('ID   Q2_1    Q2_2    Q14_1   Q15
1   Yes NA  Sometimes   NA
2   No  NA  Always  Yes
3   Yes NA  NA  NA
4   -99 No  Yes No
5   NA  -99 Always  NA
6   -99 No  NA  NA')
```

**Current solution**
I know that I can replace each of these columns individually, but I have a lot of columns to deal with and I would like to use a smart dplyr/grepl way of solving this! Any ideas? It is always the case that I am replacing the Q*.x with the Q*.y.

```
org_dat %>% mutate(Q2_1.x = case_when(!is.na(Q2_1.y) &
                                        Q2_1.x == '-99'| is.na(Q2_1.x) ~ Q2_1.y,
                                      TRUE ~ Q2_1.x)) %>%
mutate(Q2_2.x = case_when(!is.na(Q2_2.y) &
                            Q2_2.x == '-99'| is.na(Q2_2.x) ~ Q2_2.y,
                          TRUE ~ Q2_2.x)) %>% 
  
  mutate(Q14_1.x = case_when(!is.na(Q14_1.y) &
                              Q14_1.x == '-99'| is.na(Q14_1.x) ~ Q14_1.y,
                            TRUE ~ Q14_1.x)) %>%
  rename(Q2_1 = Q2_1.x,
         Q2_2 = Q2_2.x,
         Q14_1 = Q14_1.x) %>%
  select(-matches("x|y"))
```

Comment: I could not reproduce your data. Please use dput(org_data) instead of read_table

Comment: @GuedesBF I added the libraries to my code, should work now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter approach. Just strip all `".x"` suffixes off the variable names and then transmute variables whose names are not `"ID"` or do not end with `".y"`. For each of those variables, `get0` the counterpart with the `".y"` suffix and do the replacement as follows. Note that if there is no counterpart with a `".y"` suffix, `get0` returns `NULL` and `idx` thus collapses to `integer(0)`. As a result, the variable is returned as-is.

```
library(dplyr)

ord_dat %>% 
  rename_with(~sub("\\.x", "", .), ends_with(".x")) %>% 
  transmute(ID, across(!ID & !ends_with(".y"), ~{
    .y <- get0(paste0(cur_column(), ".y"))
    idx <- which(.x %in% c("-99", NA) & !is.na(.y))
    replace(.x, idx, .y[idx])
  }))
```

---

Here is a tidyverse approach. We would

1. `pivot_longer` the dataset into four columns: `ID`, `Q`(uestion), `x`, and `y`.
2. Replace any values in `x` at positions where `x` shows `NA` or `"-99"` but `y` shows a non-`NA` value.
3. Remove column `y` and `pivot_wider` the dataset with names from `Q` and values from `x`.

The steps are not complicated, but they do require granular controls of the functions. This makes the code a bit long:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ord_dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -ID, 
    names_to = c("Q", ".value"), 
    names_pattern = "([^\\.]*)\\.?([^\\.]*)", 
    names_transform = list(.value = ~replace(., . == "", "x"))
  ) %>% 
  mutate(x = {
    idx <- which(x %in% c("-99", NA) & !is.na(y))
    replace(x, idx, y[idx])
  }, y = NULL) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Q, values_from = x)
```

The output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  ID    Q2_1  Q2_2  Q14_1     Q15  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>
1 1     Yes   NA    Sometimes NA   
2 2     No    NA    Always    Yes  
3 3     Yes   NA    NA        NA   
4 4     -99   No    Yes       No   
5 5     NA    -99   Always    NA   
6 6     -99   No    NA        NA
```

Comment: As in my answer, I believe using coalesce would get this answer a bit cleaner:
`org_dat %>% 
    transmute(ID, across(!ID & !ends_with(".y"),
                         ~coalesce(.x, get0(sub('\\.x', '.y', cur_column()))))) %>%
    rename_with(~sub("\\.x", "", .), ends_with(".x"))`

Comment: Nice use of `get0` by the way. Did not know it.

Comment: @GuedesBF I thought about `coalesce`, but that would lead to `NA`s in `.x` becoming `"-99"` in `.y`. I don't think this matches the desired output that the OP shared.

Comment: @ekoam Thank you for this! Could you please explain what is happening inside the curly brackets a little more? What is ".y" ".x" ? What does the pasting do? How does replace work in this situation? I have been too tidyverse dependent and I'd like to get a firm grasp on your method.

Comment: 1) `.y` is just a variable name I chose. `.x` used inside the `~` lambda expression means the first argument passed to the function. In this case, that would be a column that is neither `ID` nor ends with `".y"`. 2) For example, `paste0(c("A", "B"), "1")` gives you a character vector `c("A1", "B1")`. Note that `cur_column()` gives you the column name that is currently being evaluated. 3) `replace(c(1,2,3), c(1,2), c(100,1000))` gives `c(100,1000,3)`. It replaces values at given positions. @NewBee

Comment: @ekoam I think I understand most of it--except for the dot in front of y and x. I can't find any helpful documents online in this kind of context. What is the purpose of "." please?

Comment: 1) That `.` has no special meaning. It just happens to be the case that R allows you to use a `.` at any position of your variable name, not like other languages in which `.` could be special. @NewBee

Comment: 2) If you know rlang's [lambda style](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/as_function.html), you should be familiar with `.x` and `.y`, which are chosen (by the package authors) as the 1st and 2nd arguments of a lambda expression. This is the case for `.x` here. However, since we only mutate 1 column each time, we would not need a `.y` argument. I just chose to reuse that symbol so that the variable names look consistent. @NewBee

Answer (score 1):

The key to the answer here is to first translate the user-defined NAs into real nas with `na_if`, followed by `coalesce` with paired columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
org_dat %>%
    na_if(-99) %>%
    mutate(across(ends_with('.x'),
                  ~coalesce(.x, get(deparse(substitute(.x)) %>%
                                        str_replace('\\.x', '.y'))))) %>%
    select(-ends_with('.y')) %>%
    rename_with(~str_remove(.x, '\\..$'))


# A tibble: 6 × 5
  ID    Q2_1  Q2_2  Q14_1     Q15  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>
1 1     Yes   NA    Sometimes NA   
2 2     No    NA    Always    Yes  
3 3     Yes   NA    NA        NA   
4 4     NA    No    Yes       No   
5 5     NA    NA    Always    NA   
6 6     NA    No    NA        NA
```

**EDIT**

The original answer did not provide the actual desired output, because it replaced all user-defined NAs (-99) with NAs.

If the OP wants to preserve these user defined NAs, We can do as follows:
First, change all columns to character.
Second, split the data.frame into dataframes paired by the prefix "Q{number}_{number}" with `split.default`.
finally, `modify` all list elements with two columns ('x' and 'y' pairs) with `modify_if` and `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

org_dat %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>%
        split.default(sub('\\..$', '', names(org_dat))) %>%
        modify_if(.p=~ncol(.x)==2, .f = ~coalesce(.x[[1]], .x[[2]])) %>%
        bind_cols() %>%
        select(ID, Q2_1, Q2_2, Q14_1, Q15)

# A tibble: 6 × 5
  ID    Q2_1  Q2_2  Q14_1     Q15  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>
1 1     Yes   NA    Sometimes NA   
2 2     -99   NA    Always    Yes  
3 3     Yes   NA    NA        NA   
4 4     -99   No    Yes       No   
5 5     NA    -99   Always    NA   
6 6     -99   No    NA        NA
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!